# Mule ESB: How to convert Binary form of payload to array in mule 4, dw 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a payload which is coming as a binary output. I need to convert this in array format.

```
"{\n  \"numberRecordsFailed\": 0,
\n  \"numberRecordsProcessed\": 0,
\n  \"stateMessage\": null,
\n  \"systemModstamp\": \"2020-10-05T03:27:28\",
\n  \"apiActiveProcessingTime\": 0,
\n  \"jobId\": \"7501q000005RsosAAC\",
\n  \"apexProcessingTime\": 0,
\n  \"createdDate\": \"2020-10-05T03:27:28\",
\n  \"id\": \"7511q000005TAMFAA4\",
\n  \"state\": \"Queued\",
\n  \"totalProcessingTime\": 0\n
```

}"

how to convert this binary payload to array...can anyone help me with this please

below is my dw2.0 expression to extract id and state

```
payload map {
CLIENT_ORDER_HEADER_ID: $.payload.id,
STATUS: $.payload.state
```

}

Comment: It is coming as binary output from where exactly? And how it is a binary? It looks like JSON. What happens if you use that DataWeave expression to convert it?

Comment: The payload which you posted looks more like a JSON Object then an Array. The payload can be converted into JSON using `read(payload, 'application/json')` function. Although that will return a JSON object and not an array. Can you please update the question to add the expected output?

Comment: data are coming from .imp file. in mule 3 to convert binary to array we can use bytetoArray component but in mule 4 that component has been removed. so not getting any clue to convert binary to array

Comment: the expected output should be {CLIENT_ORDER_HEADER_ID=7511q000005TAMFAA4, STATUS=Queued}

Answer (score 1):

I assume you get the data as a Java String.  Replace `data` with `payload` in the expression below and you can give it a try:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = "{\n  \"numberRecordsFailed\": 0,
    \n  \"numberRecordsProcessed\": 0,
    \n  \"stateMessage\": null,
    \n  \"systemModstamp\": \"2020-10-05T03:27:28\",
    \n  \"apiActiveProcessingTime\": 0,
    \n  \"jobId\": \"7501q000005RsosAAC\",
    \n  \"apexProcessingTime\": 0,
    \n  \"createdDate\": \"2020-10-05T03:27:28\",
    \n  \"id\": \"7511q000005TAMFAA4\",
    \n  \"state\": \"Queued\",
    \n  \"totalProcessingTime\": 0\n
    }"

var parsedData = read(data,"application/json")
---
{
    CLIENT_ORDER_HEADER_ID: parsedData.id,
    STATUS: parsedData.state
}
```

Note, the sample data you provided is not an array but an object.  No need to use `map`.